# C# - Saber localização do ficheiro de base de dados dinamicamente

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, arquivo, wpf

Eu estou a fazer um programa utilizando C# em WPF, e preciso de aceder á base de dados dinamicamente, neste caso estou a usar um ficheiro .mdf.
Em codigo tenho a connectionString assim:

```
string stringConexao = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=E:\PAP\Trabalhos\Trabalhos\Trabalhos.mdf; Integrated Security=True";
```

Quero substituir o "E:\PAP\Trabalhos\Trabalhos\Trabalhos.mdf", por uma forma dinamica de encontrar a base de dados, para depois poder utilizar o programa fora do meu computador.

O primeiro "\Trabalhos\" corresponde a onde está o "Trabalhos.sln", a outra pasta "Trabalhos" e "packages". Na pasta seguinte é onde tem todos os .cs, .xaml, etc.

Uma das soluções que encontrei foi colocar a base de dados dentro do /Debug, no entanto acredito que nao seja a forma adequada para fazer isso.

Desde já, Obrigado.

Comment: valentão. mande os caminhos. dos arquivos que eu pedi. o caminho completo para que eu saiba le encaminhar ao melhor caminho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TENHA COMO REFERENCIA, A PASTA DO APLICATIVO.
`E:\PAP\aplicativo.exe`

'`|DataDirectory|\`' é a pasta em que o '`aplicativo.exe`' estiver.

CASO 1: '`\aplicativo.exe`' e '`\Trabalhos.mdf`'
estão na mesma pasta
OU SEJA: '`E:\PAP\aplicativo.exe`' e '`E:\PAP\Trabalhos.mdf`'

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Trabalhos.mdf;
```

CASO 2: '`\aplicativo.exe`' e '`\Trabalhos.mdf`'
estão em pastas DIFERENTES
OU SEJA: '`E:\PAP\aplicativo.exe`' e '`E:\PAP\Trabalhos\Trabalhos\Trabalhos.mdf`'

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Trabalhos\Trabalhos\Trabalhos.mdf;
```

RESUMINDO: Use esse código. esse codigo. que dá certo.

```
string stringConexao = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Trabalhos\Trabalhos\Trabalhos.mdf; Integrated Security=True";
```

Comment: caso eu coloque como me disse, vai procurar dentro da pasta bin\Debug\Trabalhos\Trabalhos\Trabalhos.mdf, que neste caso nao existe. E eu tenho a base de dados antes do bin\Debug. não sei se é a localização adequada mas dentro do \bin\Debug sempre que ligo o Programa os dados são apagados

Comment: Talvez a forma mais adequada de fazer esta pergunta seria. Onde deve estar localizada a base de dados?

Comment: Arquivos em particoes separadas?

Comment: Como eu tinha a base de dados, dentro do Debug, ela apagava sempre que iniciava o programa novamente, no entanto já me disseram o que tinha de fazer para ela não apagar, ou seja agora ao usar  `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Trabalhos.mdf;` já resolve o problema. Obrigado e desculpe pela confusão! :)

Comment: ja passei por isso. rs rs rs pior eu ja passei por isso em ambiente de produção rs rs rs

Answer (score 0):

Olá, a resposta é simples.

Faça com que essa base de dados esteja sempre presente no diretório raíz do executável do projeto.
   Assim, pode usar a linha de código que vou mostrar a seguir para obter a localização da pasta do projeto:
    `Application.StartupPath`;

Espero ter ajudado!!

Comment: Sei que `Application.StartupPath` funciona nos WinForms, no entanto estou a utilizar WPF, no qual tal comando não existe.

Comment: Desculpa, não tenho experiência com WPF, pensava que por fazer parte na mesma do .Net Framework também tinha esse comando disponível.

Answer (score 0):

Fui pesquisar e encontrei 2 maneiras de encontrar o diretório raiz de uma aplicação WPF.

Podes fazer assim:

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Ou assim:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)
```

Espero desta vez ter ajudado! :)

Comment: Sim, agora ao verificar isso produz um resultado identico ao `|DataDirectory|`. Muito Obrigado!